# Float operation gives wrong result in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, floating-point

When running the below code

```
select 5259.56::FLOAT8=(1800.12::FLOAT8+3459.44::FLOAT8)
```

has output as false but when I run

```
select 5259.55::FLOAT8=(1800.11::FLOAT8+3459.44::FLOAT8)
```

It gives true as output. Any possible explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the floating point arithmetics. (check the link @a_horse_with_no_name provided in the comments)

To fix it and if you really need it: Type `numeric` can do exact calculations. `float` not.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html